# GPG import skips public key in file (no user ID)

Tags: public-key, gpg, import

On *computer-a* a key is generated, linking it to email aaaa@bbbbb.com, using command

```
gpg --gen-key
```

Then it is exported using command

```
gpg --export -a --output public.asc aaaa@bbbbb.com
```

The file is transferred to *computer-b* using command

```
scp public.asc root@computer-b:/root
```

At *computer-b* there is a problem importing the key (import is skipped):

```
# gpg --import public.asc
gpg: key 92310EFCC934E2FB was created 133 seconds in the future (time warp or clock problem)
gpg: key 92310EFCC934E2FB was created 133 seconds in the future (time warp or clock problem)
gpg: key 92310EFCC934E2FB was created 133 seconds in the future (time warp or clock problem)
gpg: key 92310EFCC934E2FB was created 133 seconds in the future (time warp or clock problem)
gpg: key 92310EFCC934E2FB: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```

Apparently **user ID** (i.e. *aaaa@bbbbb.com*) is expected but I can't guess how to provide it.

I am new to gpg, I have searched on Internet and can't find similar problem. Maybe the cause is too obvious?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Wait 133 seconds and try again. And fix your clocks.

Comment: I think this should answer your question : https://superuser.com/questions/1485213/gpg-cant-import-key-new-key-but-contains-no-user-id-skipped